# Ubuntu One message appearing: You do not have permission?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

i am trying to sign in to ubuntuone on my droid 2.  i keep getting a message that says the following:

You do not have permission to open this page. x-ubuntuone-contacts://syncml.one.ubuntu.com/?p=94768352&u=48325096

any ideas why, and how to fix?

Comment: i figured out the problem. you have to use the default android browser when signing up for the service.  i was using the superior browser miren :-)

Answer (score 4):

Fixed by the user, who used the default Android browser to sign up for Ubuntu One.